# Override default TextBlock style in ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a default TextBlock style defined in App.xaml, which seems to also affect the text color of ComboBox items. Now, how do I explicitly set the text color of a ComboBox defined in my main window? (I'd like to keep the default style, but have the combobox text color as, say, blue instead of red...)

**App.xaml**

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication1.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
<Application.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow">
<Grid>
    <ComboBox Name="comboBox1" SelectedIndex="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <ComboBoxItem Content = "Item1"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content = "Item2"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content = "Item3"/>
    </ComboBox>
</Grid>
```

**Things I've tried:**

1. Set Combobox.Foreground
2. Set TextElement.Foreground
3. Set TextBlock.Foreground
4. Define another implicit TextBlock style in ComboBox.Resources
5. Define another implicit TextBlock style in Grid.Resources
6. Define another implicit TextBlock style in Window.Resources

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most implicit TextBlock styles will stop at control boundaries, unless you put them in `Application.Resources`

For example, placing your style in `Window.Resources` will make it apply to all `<TextBlock>` objects, but not to text inside other Control Templates such as a `ComboBox` or a `Button`

I would suggest moving your style into `Window.Resources`, and then styling your ComboBox items to have whatever foreground color you want.

```
<ComboBox.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue" />
    </Style>
</ComboBox.Resources>
```

If you want to keep it in `Application.Resources`, then I suspect you need to track down what `x:Static` brush key is used for setting the `TextBlock.Text` color and overwrite that in your `ComboBox.Resources`

Comment: I tried adding another TextBlock style in the combobox resources.  unfortunately, it didn't have any effect.

Comment: @ErenErsonmez See my edited answer. I didn't notice you had your style in `Application.Resources`, and not `Window.Resources`

Comment: The part about styles not being applied when in Window Resources is only partially true: if in that same Resources there's also a global ComboBox style, the global TextBlock style *will* apply to the TexBlock in the ComboBox as well. I don't know why it is like that, but the fix is simple enough: within the ComboBox style add `<Style.Resources><Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}"></Style></Style.Resources>` and it will stop inheriting the globally defined one again.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use Triggers on the ComboBoxItem

```
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
     <Style.Triggers>
         <Trigger Property="ComboBoxItem.IsMouseOver" Value="true">
             <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
         </Trigger>

         <Trigger Property="ComboBoxItem.IsMouseOver" Value="false">
             <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"/>
         </Trigger>
     </Style.Triggers>
 </Style>
```

And if you want to keep it static then

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"/>
</Style>
```

Comment: Then you'll have to use an x:Key, override the default ComboBox Template, apply the template in a style, and apply the style the the ComboBox