# Why does binding affect height?

Tags: wpf, binding, styles, caliburn.micro

Style definition in Resources/Shared.xaml (**updated**):

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
<system:Double x:Key="fullHeight" >26</system:Double>
<system:Double x:Key="halfHeight" >16</system:Double>
<Thickness x:Key="m">10</Thickness>
<Style TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource fullHeight}"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="{StaticResource m}"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10"/>
</Style>
<Style TargetType="Label">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource fullHeight}"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="{StaticResource m}"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
</Style>
<Style TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource fullHeight}"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="{StaticResource m}"/>
</Style>
<Style TargetType="TextBox">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource fullHeight}"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="{StaticResource m}"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10"/>
</Style>
<Style TargetType="PasswordBox">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource fullHeight}"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="{StaticResource m}"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10"/>
</Style>
<Style TargetType="ListView">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource fullHeight}"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="{StaticResource m}"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10"/>
</Style>
<Style TargetType="ComboBox">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="{StaticResource m}"/>
</Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Window:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="../Resources/Shared.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

User control:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
  <Label Content="Text" Background="AliceBlue"/>
  <Label Content="{Binding DecimalValue, FallbackValue=50}" Background="Aquamarine"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Model:

```
    private decimal _DecimalValue;
    public decimal DecimalValue
    {
        get { return _DecimalValue; }
        set
        {
            if (_DecimalValue != value)
            {
                _DecimalValue = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange();
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm using Caliburn.Micro if it makes any difference.

Result:

[image]

Why?

**Update:** After some Snooping, it turns out that the inner TextBlock of the first Label has margin of 0 and Value Source is Default and for the second it's 10 and Style.

**Update 2:** After reading up [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9035878/implicit-styles-in-application-resources-vs-window-resources) it turns out that defined `TextBlock` style should *not* be applied to `TextBlocks` inside `Labels`. So it seems that existence of binding on a `Label` somehow changes that.

Comment: Please show the definition of `fullHeight` and `m`.

Comment: Just tried this in VS2012/.NET4.5.  Works fine in the designer and at runtime - both labels the same height.  Which version of VS are you using?

Comment: Have you tried these snippets stand alone? Maybe you have some other style that's getting applied?

Comment: @Gaz I don't think so. Even if I had another style somewhere, what would discriminate between the two labels?

Comment: @Phil Same config as yours.

Comment: Clutching at straws - I have VS2012 update 2 installed.

Comment: @user676571: Just wondered if you'd sanitised the xaml for posting on here and inadvertently removed something that might be affecting it (eg an id tag). I've done the same myself before now.

Comment: @Gaz I'll give more context in a minute, but I'm not sure it will help.

Comment: Is it displayed wrong during runtime or during design time in VS?

Comment: @Jehof Image is taken from the runtime. In design time those styles do not apply as they are defined in the window.

Comment: It's working fine for me as well. If you create a completely new project and copy/paste the content found in this question there, do you experience the same problem? That should tell us if it's something to do with your application or your system.

Answer (score 1):

You must have some other style affecting it.

My best guess would be check your `Padding` properties, because when I copy and paste your styles to a new project, the heights and margins are the same as your image, however the Padding is different.

Your Labels are actually getting rendered like this:

```
<Label>
    <Border>
        <ContentPresenter>
            <TextBlock />
        </ContentPresenter>
    </Border>
</Label>
```

By messing around with [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/), I can duplicate your image by altering the Padding of the `Border` object, so check your XAML to see if you have any implicit styles that change the `Padding` of your `Border` tags

**Update**

After adding the extra styles you've added to your question, I am able to reproduce the results you are getting.

The problem appears to be that the implicit style for your `TextBlock` is being applied to the `TextBlock` inside the bound label, but not to the unbound one.

It should be noted this only happens when binding to a decimal value, not to a string.

I suspect this is related to the fact that [implicit styles are not meant to cross template boundaries](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsdk/archive/2009/08/27/implicit-styles-templates-controls-and-frameworkelements.aspx), *unless* the element inherits from `Control`. `Label` inherits from `Control`, however `TextBlock` does not.

Since this only happens when binding to a numeric value, my best guess is that the process that determines how to draw a Decimal for `Label.Content` identifies the parent control as a `Label`, while the process that writes a `string` to `Label.Content` automatically knows to use a `TextBlock`, and does not apply the implicit styles.

Comment: Snoop FTW. This tool is great. I was wondering if there is something that would enable style debugging. Anyway, it tells me that the inner `TextBlock` of the first `Label` has margin of 0 and Value Source is Default and for the second it's 10 and Style. What could be the cause? I should update the question to include whole Shared.xaml

Comment: @user676571 It's probably an implicit style somewhere that is only affecting one of your TextBlocks due to it's scope. Search your XAML for a style that specifies a type of `TextBlock`, but no `x:Key`, like this: `<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" />`

Comment: Exactly. Question is, why is it not affectiong the other one?

Comment: @user676571 I'm not sure, is that your complete XAML? Your style can have a different scope depending on where it's located. For example, `<Window.Resources>` will apply to everything, while `<UserControl.Resources>` will only apply to that user control.

Comment: That is all there is. All implicit styles are defined in `Shared.xaml`.

Comment: @user676571 When you view your application in Snoop, do both `Labels` contain the exact same set of tags? (Border, ContentPresenter, and TextBlock)

Comment: Yes, they do. Structure is the same, the only difference is that from the first comment: the inner TextBlock of the first Label has margin of 0 and Value Source is Default and for the second it's 10 and Style.

Comment: Perhaps I am misreading your update, but in this case `Label` bound to a decimal *has* margin. To me it seems as if binding mechanism is applying implicit style across template boundary. On a side note, it seems odd that nobody has encountered this before. Are styles not meant to be used in this way?

Comment: @user676571 Sorry, I had that backwards and have updated it. I'm actually asking [a different SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15951456/302677) about this since I'm quite curious what the actual logic is behind this :)

Comment: No problem. Let's hope your question will attract more attention :)