# Why does an implicit TextBlock style get applied when binding Label.Content to a non-string, but not a string?

Tags: wpf, styles, label, implicit-style

I was looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15922964/why-does-binding-affect-height), and discovered that binding `Label.Content` to a non-string value will apply an implicit `TextBlock` style, however binding to a string does not.

Here's some sample code to reproduce the problem:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Label">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="26"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="26"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label Content="{Binding SomeString}" Background="Red"/>
        <Label Content="{Binding SomeDecimal}" Background="Green"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Where the code for the bound values are

```
SomeDecimal = 50;
SomeString = SomeDecimal.ToString();
```

And the end result looks like this, with the `Margin` property from the implicit TextBlock style getting applied to the Label bound to a non-string only:

[image]

Both labels get rendered as

```
<Label>
    <Border>
        <ContentPresenter>
            <TextBlock />
        </ContentPresenter>
    </Border>
</Label>
```

When I check out the VisualTree with [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/), I can see that it looks exactly the same for both elements, except the 2nd TextBlock applies the Margin from the implicit style, while the first does not.

[image]

I've used Blend to pull out a copy of the default Label Template, but don't see anything strange there, and when I apply the template to both my labels, the same thing happens.

```
<Label.Template>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
        <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" 
                SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
            <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" 
                              Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" 
                              ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentStringFormat}" 
                              HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                              RecognizesAccessKey="True" 
                              SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" 
                              VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
        </Border>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Label.Template>
```

It should also be noted that setting a default `ContentTemplate` to a `TextBlock` does make both items render without the implicit style, so it must have something to do with when WPF tries to render a non-string value as part of the UI.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Label">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="26"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="TemplatedStyle" TargetType="Label" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Label}}">
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding }"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="26"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label Content="{Binding SomeString}" Background="Red"/>
        <Label Content="{Binding SomeDecimal}" Background="Green"/>
        <Label Content="{Binding SomeString}" Background="Red" 
               Style="{StaticResource TemplatedStyle}"/>
        <Label Content="{Binding SomeDecimal}" Background="Green" 
               Style="{StaticResource TemplatedStyle}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

[image]

What is the logic that causes a non-string inserted into the UI to be drawn using an implicit TextBlock style, but a string inserted into the UI does not? And where does this occur at?

Comment: This question intrigued me, so i had to start the old reflector. Well there is only one thing i could find so far. It seems TextBlock makes a distinction between simple text and "complex" objects, it uses two different subclasses for both. Unfortunately this is where it ends. I can't find any trace of a specialized style or anything. One thing to try is to provide a ContentTemplate with a TextBlock and check if that changes something. In that case it could have something to do with that mystical default template.

Comment: @dowhilefor I tried pulling the default template from Blend and applying it to both labels, and the same thing happens (question updated with that info). My only guess would be WPF knows to render a `System.String` as a `TextBlock` without implicit styling, but when it goes to render a non-string value, it draws it as a `TextBlock` bound to the `.ToString()` of the object, and applies any implicit styling.

Comment: @dowhilefor You are correct though that setting the default `ContentTemplate` to a `<TextBlock Text="{Binding }" />` does make both items render without the implicit style, so it looks like it has something to do with the default `ContentTemplate` for non-string objects

Comment: Ok i got some more infos. I think the reason for that is the ContentPresenter itself, his default Template seems to be constructed in code. The internal class is actually called DefaultTemplate and inside you find the creation of a TextBlock. I still have no clue where the style applying comes in, but i would consider this a bug possible by the order of creation and handling the different contents.

Comment: This is not only a problem with Label. This can also be reproduced using ContentControl (base type of Label). And it is not a binding problem, cause the same effect can be reproduced when defining and Int32 and String as Resource and using it as StaticResource/DynamicResource

Comment: @Jehof Thanks, I've updated my post a bit to clarify the exact problem - inserting a string into the UI will *not* apply an implicit TextBlock style, however inserting a non-string into the UI does. I'm trying to determine why that is and how it happens.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** (maybe move this to the bottom?)

And I poked a bit more - and **I think I got to the crux of the problem** (w/ emphasis on 'I think')

**Put this into some `Button1_Click` or something** (again, we need to go 'lazy' on this - as we need the visual tree constructed - we cannot do it on 'Loaded' as we just made the templates - this required better initialization technique true, but it's just a test so who cares)

```
void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
var insideTextBlock = FindVisualChild<TextBlock>(_labelString);
var value = insideTextBlock.GetProperty<bool>("HasImplicitStyleFromResources"); // false
value = insideTextBlock.GetProperty<bool>("ShouldLookupImplicitStyles"); // true

var boundaryElement = insideTextBlock.TemplatedParent; // ContentPresenter and != null

insideTextBlock = FindVisualChild<TextBlock>(_labelDecimal);
value = insideTextBlock.GetProperty<bool>("HasImplicitStyleFromResources"); // true
value = insideTextBlock.GetProperty<bool>("ShouldLookupImplicitStyles"); // true

boundaryElement = insideTextBlock.TemplatedParent; // == null !!
```

As mentioned here [Implicit styles in Application.Resources vs Window.Resources?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9035878/implicit-styles-in-application-resources-vs-window-resources)
The `FindImplicitStyleResource` (in `FrameworkElement`) uses something like...

```
boundaryElement = fe.TemplatedParent;
```

> And seems that **if there is no `TemplatedParent`** (and due to the ways
>   the `TextBlock` is constructed within the `DefaultTemplate`) - **there
>   are no 'boundaries' set - and search for implicit resources / styles -
>   propagates all the way**.

---

---

**Original Answer:** (read this first if you just arrived)

(@dowhilefor and @Jehof already touched on the main things)
I'm not sure this is an 'answer' as such - it's still a guess work - but I needed more space to explain what I think is going on.

You can find the 'ContentPresenter source' code on the web - it's easier than using reflector - just 'google' for it, I'm not posting it here for the obvious reasons :)

It's about the `ContentTemplate` that is chosen for the `ContentPresenter` (and in this order)...

```
ContentTemplate // if defined 
ContentTemplateSelector // if defined
FindResource // for typeof(Content) - eg if defined for sys:Decimal takes that one
DefaultTemplate used internally by the presenter
...specific templates are chosen based on typeof(Content)
```

And indeed it doesn't have anything to do with the `Label` but any ContentControl or control template that uses `ContentPresenter`. Or you could bind to resource etc.

Here is **a repro of what's going on inside** - **my goal was to reproduce similar behavior for 'strings'** or any type of content.

In XAML just 'name' the labels (and it isn't a typo, a deliberately put strings in both to level the playing field sort of)...

```
<Label Name="_labelString" Content="{Binding SomeString}" Background="Red"/>
<Label Name="_labelDecimal" Content="{Binding SomeString}" Background="Green"/>
```

And from code behind (the minimal code that sort of mimics what presenter does):
note: I did it on `Loaded` as I needed access to the presenter implicitly created

```
void Window1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
FrameworkElementFactory factory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
factory.SetValue(TextBlock.TextProperty, new TemplateBindingExtension(ContentProperty));
var presenterString = FindVisualChild<ContentPresenter>(_labelString);
presenterString.ContentTemplate = new DataTemplate() { VisualTree = factory };

// return;

var presenterDecimal = FindVisualChild<ContentPresenter>(_labelDecimal);
presenterDecimal.ContentTemplate = new DataTemplate(); 
// just to avoid the 'default' template kicking in

// this is what 'default template' does actually, the gist of it
TextBlock textBlock = new TextBlock();
presenterDecimal.SetProperty(typeof(FrameworkElement), "TemplateChild", textBlock);
textBlock.Text = presenterDecimal.Content.ToString();
```

First part (for `_labelString`) does what 'text' template does for strings.

If you `return` right after that - you'll get the two same looking boxes, no implicit template.

Second part (for `_labelDecimal`) mimics the 'default template' which is invoked for the 'decimal'.

> End result should behave the same as the original example. We
>   constructed the templates as for the `string` and `decimal` - but we
>   can put anything in the content (if it makes sense of course).

**As to why** - my guess is something like this (though far from certain - somebody will jump in with something more sensible I guess)...

As per this link [FrameworkElementFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelementfactory(v=vs.100).aspx)

> This class is a deprecated way to programmatically create templates,
>   which are subclasses of FrameworkTemplate such as ControlTemplate or
>   DataTemplate; not all of the template functionality is available when
>   you create a template using this class. The recommended way to
>   programmatically create a template is to load XAML from a string or a
>   memory stream using the Load method of the XamlReader class.

And I'm guessing it doesn't invoke any defined styles for the TextBlock.

While the 'other template' (default template) - actually constructs the `TextBlock` and somewhere along those lines - it actually picks up the implicit style.

Frankly, that's as much as I was able to conclude, short of going through the entire WPF 'internals' and how/where actually styles get applied.

---

I used this code [Finding control within WPF itemscontrol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/980120/finding-control-within-wpf-itemscontrol/984862#984862) for `FindVisualChild`.
And the `SetProperty` is just the reflection - for that one property we need access to to be able to do all this. e.g.

```
public static void SetProperty<T>(this object obj, string name, T value) { SetProperty(obj, obj.GetType(), name, value); }
public static void SetProperty<T>(this object obj, Type typeOf, string name, T value)
{
    var property = typeOf.GetProperty(name, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public);
    property.SetValue(obj, value, null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After going through this question and valuable comments from all, I have done some research on   TextBlock Styling.

To my understanding the problem here is not with the Label or TextBlock, it is with the contentpresenter and the controls which use contentpresenter like Label, button and ComboBoxItem.

One of the properties of content presenter from MSDN : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentpresenter.aspx

**" If there is a TypeConverter that converts the type of Content to a string, the ContentPresenter uses that TypeConverter and creates a TextBlock to contain that string. The TextBlock is displayed "**

In the example above, For SomeString Content presenter is converting it into textblock and applying the TextBlock margin (10) along with Label margin (10) making it 20.

In order to avoid this scenario you need to override the TextBlock style in contentpresenter as shown below

```
                           <ContentPresenter >
                               <ContentPresenter.Resources>
                                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
                                    </Style>
                                </ContentPresenter.Resources>
                            </ContentPresenter>
```

Following is the changes to your code.

```
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="26"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10"/>

            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>

                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Label">
                        <Grid>
                            <Rectangle Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
                            <ContentPresenter >
                                <ContentPresenter.Resources>
                                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
                                    </Style>
                                </ContentPresenter.Resources>
                            </ContentPresenter>
                        </Grid>

                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="26"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Pink" />
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label Content="{Binding SomeString}" Background="Red" />
            <Label Content="{Binding SomeDecimal}" Background="Green"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

This explanation is just based on my understanding. Let me know your comments.

Thanks

Comment: I've actually added a bit to my question which explains that if you overwrite the `ContentTemplate` of the Label, it stops applying the implicit TextBlock style. My question is more about why placing a string in the UI *does* apply the implicit style, while placing a non-string (which is then converted to a string) in the UI does not. I think you may be close with the MSDN quote though. I suspect that the process that uses a `TypeConverter` to create a `TextBlock` is applying any implicit styles, regardless of template boundaries.

Comment: @Rachel - `TypeConverter` is just where I made `textBlock.Text = presenter.Content.ToString();` (I can post the code - and the full link if you wish - but I was just reluctant to share that) - it fills the text at the very 'end'. It has nothing to do with creating the TextBlock (templates do). See my `EDIT` - problem is with the `boundaries` actually.

Answer (score 0):

According to my comment i add more information to the question. Its not a direct answer, but provides additional information to the described problem.

The XAML below will display the described behavior directly in the Designer of Visual Studio and i have narrowed it down to the ContentPresenter, which seems to be source of the problem. The style gets applied to the first both ContentPresenter (`intPresenter` and `boolPresenter`), but not the last that uses a string as Content (`stringPresenter`).

```
<Window.Resources>
  <system:Int32 x:Key="intValue">5</system:Int32>
  <system:Boolean x:Key="boolValue">false</system:Boolean>
  <system:String x:Key="stringValue">false</system:String>
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="26" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10" />
  </Style>
</Window.Resources>

 <Grid>
   <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
     <ContentPresenter x:Name="intPresenter" 
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       Content="{StaticResource intValue}" />
     <ContentPresenter x:Name="boolPresenter" 
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       Content="{StaticResource boolValue}" />
     <ContentPresenter x:Name="stringPresenter"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       Content="{StaticResource stringValue}" />
   </StackPanel>
  </Grid>
```

In the debugger i have analyzed that the `stringPresenter` uses the DefaultStringTemplate while the `intPresenter` does not.

[image]

<sub>Its also interesting that the `Language` of the `intPresenter` is set, while by the `stringPresenter` its not.</sub>

And the implementation of the method looks something like that (taken from dotPeek)

```
private bool IsUsingDefaultStringTemplate
    {
      get
      {
        if (this.Template == ContentPresenter.StringContentTemplate || this.Template == ContentPresenter.AccessTextContentTemplate)
          return true;
        DataTemplate dataTemplate1 = ContentPresenter.StringFormattingTemplateField.GetValue((DependencyObject) this);
        if (dataTemplate1 != null && dataTemplate1 == this.Template)
          return true;
        DataTemplate dataTemplate2 = ContentPresenter.AccessTextFormattingTemplateField.GetValue((DependencyObject) this);
        return dataTemplate2 != null && dataTemplate2 == this.Template;
      }
    }
```

The StringContentTemplate and AccessTextTemplate are using a FrameworkElementFactory to generate the Visuals.