# WPF ControlTemplate inherit style from parent resources

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm styling hyperlinks that appear within a border with the style "FooterPanel" as follows:

```
<Style x:Key="FooterPanel" TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Hyperlink}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource FooterPanelLinkBrush}"/>
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

I also now have created a style to create a button as a hyperlink (so I can get properties such as IsDefault and IsCancel on a hyperlink):

```
<Style x:Key="LinkButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <Hyperlink Command="{TemplateBinding Command}" CommandParameter="{TemplateBinding CommandParameter}">
                        <Run Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                    </Hyperlink>
                </TextBlock>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Normal hyperlinks within FooterPanel receive the FooterPanelLinkBrush foreground, but if I use LinkButton within a FooterPanel, the style is not applied. Is there a way to get the ControlTemplate to inherit the styles within the FooterPanel instead of any global hyperlink styles?

**Edit:**

According to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/9166963/2383681 there is special handling that means the `Hyperlink` won't receive the styles defined in the `FooterPanel` as it's not derived from `Control`.

I'm not sure what I'm trying to do is therefore possible without some code-behind, so I think I'm just going to workaround this and create a new style for `FooterPanelLinkButton` and explicitly reference this for the buttons that are in a footer panel. It would be interesting to know if this is possible however without doing that.

Comment: You could use [BasedOn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.basedon(v=vs.110).aspx) but that would make every LinkButton have the footerpanel style not just ones within the footerpanel

Answer (score 1):

You can create a separate `Style` for the `HyperLink`:

```
<Style x:Key="FooterPanelLink" TargetType="{x:Type Hyperlink}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource FooterPanelLinkBrush}"/>
</Style>
```

And then use this `Style` in the `Resources` of the `FooterPanel` and `LinkButton` styles in the following way:

```
<Style x:Key="FooterPanel" TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Hyperlink" BasedOn="{StaticResource FooterPanelLink}" />
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="LinkButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Hyperlink" BasedOn="{StaticResource FooterPanelLink}" />
    </Style.Resources>

    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <Hyperlink Command="{TemplateBinding Command}" CommandParameter="{TemplateBinding CommandParameter}">
                        <Run Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                    </Hyperlink>
                </TextBlock>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

This way the `HyperLink` inside the `LinkButton` will use the color you assigned in the `FooterPanelLink` style.

Comment: This changes the `Hyperlink` inside the `LinkButton` to always be the `FooterPanelLink` - I'm hoping there's a way I can say it should use the global styles, unless it's inside a `FooterPanel` and it should then use `FooterPanelLink`.