# Global TextBlock style messing with named Label style

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I created a very simple WPF application with the following resources:

```
<Application x:Class="StyleTest.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
<Application.Resources>
    <FontFamily x:Key="MainFontFamily">Calibri</FontFamily>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource MainFontFamily}" />
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="HyperlinkLabel" TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
        <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Yellow" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

</Application.Resources>
```

The TextBlock style doesn't have a x:Key property. I want this property to apply to all the TextBlocks.

The UI is simply:

```
<Window x:Class="StyleTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="Test 123 Test 123" Style="{StaticResource HyperlinkLabel}" />

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

When I run the application:

1. "Test 123 Test 123" is displayed in yellow.
2. When I put the mouse cursor over the text, the mouse cursor icon changes to a hand with a pointing finger.
3. When I put the mouse cursor over the text, the text turns red.

Great. But if I changed the first style from:

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource MainFontFamily}" />
    </Style>
```

to

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource MainFontFamily}" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue" />
    </Style>
```

Then, when running the application:

1. The text is displayed in blue instead of yellow. This is bad.
2. When I put the mouse cursor over the text, the mouse cursor icon changes to a hand with a pointing finger. This is ok.
3. When I put the mouse cursor over the text, the text stays blue. This is bad.

Why is the TextBlock style messing up with the Label style? I seems that Label inherits from TextBlock. But even if it is the case, the Label style should be used no?

How can I “force” the use of the Label style? How can the Label style overwritte the TextBlock style?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implicit styles in `Application.Resources` applied to non-control items such as `TextBlock` do not respect control boundaries, and will apply to the entire application regardless of what other definitions exist. This was probably done to allow for global application-wide styling, such as font, text sizes, colors, etc.

Two solutions to fix this :

1. Change implicit style to a `Label`, which inherits from `Control`. Because it is a Control, it will respect control boundaries and not try to overwrite the properties of every text element in your application.
2. Move the style to `Window.Resources` instead of `Application.Resources`. This way the style isn't considered global for the entire application, so isn't treated as such when deciding how to render items.

I had the same question a while back, and this is the best I could make of the description given. [Implicit styles in Application.Resources vs Window.Resources?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9035878/302677) :)

Comment: Thanks @Rachel. Actually, I learned that a label contains a textblock [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/fa7eac3c-594c-4ed3-9da8-6134234123ed/textblock-style-messing-up-with-label-style?forum=wpf). That explains a lot.