# WPF unwanted style inheritance

Tags: wpf

In my `ResourceDictionary` I'm setting default style for `TextBlock`:

```xml
<Style TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource TextBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10" />
</Style>
```

Then when I put lets say a `CheckBox` it looks fine in the designer but on runtime the `TextBlock` inside the `CheckBox` has that `10 margin`.

What can cause that to happen?...

I'm setting the resources inside `App.xaml.cs`(Because I'm not using `StartUri`):

```cs
_mainView.Resources.Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/App;component/Resources/DarkTheme.xaml"); // Colors and brushes

ResourceDictionary style = new ResourceDictionary
{
    Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/App;component/Resources/Style.xaml")
};

_mainView.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(style); // Styles
```

Comment: It is a default Style that is applied to all TextBlocks in your application, also those created by other UI elements. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9035878/1136211

Comment: @Clemens but in my case it's in reverse..